# How to store NSDictionary easily on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary and I need to save and load it in memory. For example, it's easy to save NSString in NSUserDefaults. Help me please :)

Comment: You can do it, but why don't you look for a good tutorial before asking it?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri if you give me a link with tutorial I'll be happy :)

Comment: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as the contents of your dictionary conforms to the requirements, you can use [-[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBHDB) or [-[NSDictionary writeToURL:atomically:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BCIICEDB) to persist the dictionary and then use [+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHEADHI) or [+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BCIDGEBC) to read the file back into the dictionary.

The [MVCNetworking sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BCIDGEBC) includes some code that does this.